# open flow controller + openvswitch. how?

Tags: openvswitch

I have a computer that's running openvswitch and I want to create a backup.
I'm thinking about moving the controller away from the server on which openvswitch runs, and create multiple openvswitch servers that are all bound to one controller.

I have a bunch of rules that I've created using ovs-ofctl, some of them are learning rules.
Is it possible to move ovs-controller to a different machine and keep using ovs-ofctl?
or do i need a completely different controller?

Thanks!